# Jquery Change input text position and name

Tags: php, jquery, drag-and-drop

I don´t know if this it´s possible by this my question and i´ll try writte the best i can my question

I have one form with 5 fields , all fields when i send form his values insert using php with foreach loop , the fields and values receive in the order i have in the form no in other

I try with jquery change order and put for example the first field in the last position and other fields also i change his position using jquery draggable

The problem i see , it´s for example my fields in the form have in his name one number , for example :

```
<INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="TABLE[V0]" VALUE="">

<INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="TABLE[V1]" VALUE="">

<INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="TABLE[V2]" VALUE="">

<INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="TABLE[V3]" VALUE="">

<INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="TABLE[V4]" VALUE="">

<INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="TABLE[V5]" VALUE="">
```

Whith jquery draggable i can change position , but when launch the form receive in the same order and no change order really , by this if i change the first field to the last , in first position i continue receive the first value in first position and no in the last , by this my question is if it´s possible change the name of field when we change position by the position of other field , etc

I don´t know if it´s very difficult but i supose it´s possible , but i try differents ways but no get the results i want

I hope understand the idea , sorry if no possible understand all fine , i try tell 
the best i can , thank´s , the best regards

Answer (score 0):

The PHP will process the form in the order that it is defined in the PHP file. If you need the form to be processed in a different order try posting a JSON object from jQuery via Ajax. You will then need to handle what the app does next.

Comment: Do you know some example ?